# C++ I/O numbers in text file

Tags: c++, matrix, io

I'm trying to read numbers from a test file and display them in a matrix. In the text file, there is one number per line. The first two lines are the dimensions of the matrix.(3 and 4) I'm having trouble assigning the actual data values of these numbers to the matrix. In this case Values 2 through 14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h> 
using namespace std;
#include "Matrix.h"

int main()
{
        CMatrix A(10,10); //set to arbitrary size
        int x;
        int i = 0;
        int number;
        int rowsFile;
        int columnsFile;

        while ( myFile.good()&& myFile.is_open() )
        {
            myFile>>x;  
            if (i==0){ //for row dimension
                rowsFile = x; 
            }

            if (i==1){ //for column dimension
                columnsFile = x;
            }
            cout<<"Value "<<i<<": "<<x<<endl; //displays the values


            if (i>=2){
                for (int r = 0; r < rowsFile; r++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < columnsFile; c++)
                    {
                        A.Value(r,c) = x;
                        myFile>>x;  
                    }
                }
                myFile.close();
            }


            i=i+1;
        }
        myFile.close();

        CMatrix A(rowsFile, columnsFile);
        cout<<endl<< "Rows: "<<A.getNumberOfRows()<<endl;
        cout<< "Columns: "<<A.getNumberOfColumns()<<endl;
        cout<<endl<<A.ToString();
}
```

Here is a display of my output.
[image]

For some reason my commented out loop doesn't seem to be working.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's a little confusing what you're trying to do here.  First, you probably need to increment `i` after reading the `rowsFile` and `columnsFile` value.  Second, you probably need to store the values of `x` if you process the input in one loop, and populate the matrix in another.  Also, the `i` in your proposed `for` loop would "shadow" the other `i` you are using, which is confusing.

Comment: Do **not** use `file.eof()` to attempt working out if input was successful! It does **not** work! Also, **always** check **after** the input if it was successful. Compared to these two points, it is a marginal point: use `std::istringstream` when you need to input from a string, not `std::stringstream`. Note, that creating and destroying streams is a rather heavy operation, i.e., you will not possibly arrive at something which can be remotely labeled as fast.

Comment: I saw your comment below.  Moving forward.  It looks like you declare CMatrix A _twice_: once at the top of `main`, and then right before printing `Rows:` and `Columns`.  In fact, I'm surprised the compiler will let you do that, since they're in the same scope.  Try removing the second declaration, and if that doesn't work, add a print statement within the innermost loop.

Comment: @NicholasM Thanks for the response. Yes, I declared it twice because it specifies how big the matrix should be in the text file. What I thought was to create the matrix and then change the dimensions later using the variables, _rowsFile_ and _columnsFile_. Anyways, what you said worked but I'm stuck with an incorrectly sized matrix with values in it. Do you know how I could go about changing this? Thanks!

Comment: The only approaches I can see are the two you mention in your comment:  (1) initialize the matrix first with a fixed size, say 1x1, and then resize it _after_ reading the row and column sizes, but before reading values, if the CMatrix class provides that functionality.  Or (2) initialize the matrix after reading the two row and column sizes.

Comment: @NicholasM I figured it could be resolved like that. The problem is that this will all be within the reading of the file. I'd like to be able to use this object and modify it outside of this loop. Where can I go from here? Could I change around the matrix class to support this somehow?

Answer (score 2):

While I can't offer you a complete solution due not completely understanding what you're trying to do, I recommend reading the contents of the file line wise and storing them in a vector, as in this example:

```
std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
std::string line;
std::vector<std::string> lines;
if (ifs.good()) while (getline(ifs, line)) lines.push_back(line);
else throw std::runtime_error("An error occurred while trying to read from file.");
```

This makes it easier to work with the data.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you reorganize this code to place doubles into matrix elements immediately after reading them.

The file io code may not be perfect, but I would separate the reading of the number of rows and columns from the loop that handles the element values.

```
// do not declare i here
int numRows;
int numCols;

std::fstream inputFile("filename", std::in);

if ! (inputFile >> numRows >> numCols) 
{
    // Handle error 
}

// Check that numRows and numCols are acceptable (positive)
// [not shown] 

CMatrix A(numRows, numCols);
if (inputFile)
{
    int elementsRead = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
        {
            double x;
            if (inputFile >> x)
            { 
                A.Value(i,j) = x;
                ++elementsRead;
            } else {
                // probably an error from too-short file, 
                // token could not be converted to double, etc.
                // handle appropriately
                break;  
            }
        }
    }
}

if (elementsRead != numRows * numCols)
{
    // handle error
}

// Use matrix A
```

Comment: I tried to use this logic to no avail. I updated my question. Hopefully it makes more sense.